# How to close linked table in H2db?

Tags: sql, h2

Is there a syntax to close a table link? In other words, what is the opposite of `create linked table LocalTableToBe( className, url, userName, password, RemoteTableSource )`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only drop these table links with the regular `DROP TABLE` command:

```sql
DROP TABLE LocalTableToBe;
```

This command drops the specified link, the actual table in another database isn't affected by it.